# How to repeat a simple Get-Content Out-File command for a list of objects in a different dataset?

Tags: powershell, loops, csv, search, foreach

here is my problem:
I have a list of only lastnames stored in a smallfile.csv. Each name is a separate line.
I have a second hugefile.csv with several strings per line among them somewhere the last name.
Now I want to search each lastname of smallfile.csv in hugefile.csv and save the resulting hits.

I managed to do this manually for one lastname at a time using the following command line:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Y\Y\MAG\hugefile.csv' –read 10000000 | foreach { $_ -match "Smith"}|Out-File 'C:\Y\Y\MAG\Smith.csv'
```

How can I loop over this command drawing from the first file?
I tried something like this which did not work:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\Y\Y\MAG\smallfile.csv') {
Get-Content 'C:\Y\Y\MAG\hugefile.csv' | foreach { $_ -match $line}| Out-File 'C:\Y\Y\MAG\$line.csv' -append
}
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Can you show a **small** snippet of the two `.csv` files?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
$rootPath = "C:\Y\Y\MAG\"

$smallFilePath = $rootPath + "smallfile.csv"
$hugeFilePath = $rootPath + "hugefile.csv"

$smallFile = Get-Content -Path $smallFilePath

foreach ($line in $smallFile)
{
    $outPath = $rootPath + $line + ".csv"
    Get-Content -Path $hugeFilePath | Where { $_ -match $line } | Out-File $outPath
}
```